# Axios in React for storing response for future use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I'm trying to use the response returned by an Axios GET request for displaying it on my webpage. However, when I'm trying to store the response using the useState hook in a state variable, I'm not getting the API fetched data in my state variable.

I figure it has something to do with the async nature of Axios. Any help on how I can successfully store it in the state would greatly help. Thanks.

```
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('');

axios.get('/URL', {
   params: {
        ABC: 'abc',
        XYZ: '150'
    }
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
  setResponseData(response.data);
}, (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})

console.log('ResponseData: ' + responseData);
```

Comment: Show the full code, that's a practically infinite loop if the get request isn't inside useEffect or similar, and the value of responseData depends on where and when you're logging it.

Comment: @GuyIncognito This is practically the relevant code right now, I'm trying to use the responseData value later in my code. However, it's not updated with the setResponseData, this probably means that it's getting executed before Axios sends me the response. How to tackle this? Using UseEffect?

Comment: How do you check your state after getting the response and calling setResponseData? Now the console.log is not waiting for the response, so you are printing the value of responseData before it is updated

Comment: @jamomani Yes, so how do I ensure that I wait for the whole response before using setResponseData and then printing the value? Is useEffect a good place to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Infinite loop -> so call with UseEffect

The problem with the code is that when `setResponseData` update the response, the whole component rerender and that's make `axios` call again and again.

My solution is call with useEffect.

```
export default function App() {

  const [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      await axios.get('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', {
        params: { ABC: 'abc', XYZ: '150' }
      }).then((response) => {
        setResponseData({ response: response.data, check: Date.now() });
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    })();
  }, [])

  console.log('ResponseData:', responseData);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>lalla</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So now we get empty in the initial render and after fetch we get the data :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch data in a component then the best way to properly do this is via `useEffect` hook:

```
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get('/URL', {
               params: {
                    ABC: 'abc',
                    XYZ: '150'
               }
            });
            setResponseData(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
    fetchData();
}, []); // with no dependencies, this hook will run only on component mount

// Hook below serves only to confirm when data lands in your responseData state
useEffect(() => {
    if (responseData) console.log('ResponseData: ' + responseData);
}, [ responseData ]);
```